# Bluemix language identify does not identify English

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

So I am beta-testing the Language Translate - Identify API and it is very strange - it identifies Spanish very well but not English.  Huh?  Check this out...

Go to https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/language-translation-v2#!/identify/identifyLanguageGet

Paste this text in the box:

Michael+is+a+hard+working+student+who+shows+responsibility+in+his+daily+tasks.+He+is+enthusiastic%2C+engaged+and+active+in+his+learning%2C+all+qualities+shown+through+his+level+of+participation+and+ability+to+self-assess+his+work.+He+has+become+very+good+at+identifying+his+strengths+and+uses+feedback+to+improve+and+revise+his+assignments.+Congratulations+on+a+great+first+semester.

I get back "et" which is ESTONIAN.  Huh?

And if I enter this text (same as before but with one more character at the end):

Michael+is+a+hard+working+student+who+shows+responsibility+in+his+daily+tasks.+He+is+enthusiastic%2C+engaged+and+active+in+his+learning%2C+all+qualities+shown+through+his+level+of+participation+and+ability+to+self-assess+his+work.+He+has+become+very+good+at+identifying+his+strengths+and+uses+feedback+to+improve+and+revise+his+assignments.+Congratulations+on+a+great+first+semester.%21

I get "ja" which is JAPANESE.  I also get "ht" which is HAITIAN CREOLE from time to time....Hello Watson??  English??

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: yes - question is why don't I get English?

Comment: Because the online UI expects plain text, not URL-encoded text. If you remove the `+`-signs and paste "Michael is a hard working..." you get English.

Comment: yes I agree that the problem is somewhere in the encoding.  I arrived at this problem via the API where I have to encode.  Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an encoding issue.  Everything must be strictly in UTF-8 as docs say.

FYI in a POST request, even though you do need to encode the text, the text must also be strictly in UTF-8.  This was one of my challenges as obviously you're dealing with lots of accented characters with Language Translate.